# Sampling a random binary matrix with "Gaussian" probability distribution

Tags: matrix, gibbs, normalizing-constant, markov-random-field

Let $A_{ij}$ be a $n\times n$ random binary matrix with probability mass function $P(A)$ given by
$$
\log P(A)=-\frac 12 \mathrm{tr}\left[\left(A-M\right)^TV\left(A-M\right)\right] + C,
$$
where $M$ and $V$ are also $n\times n$ matrices, $\mathrm{tr}$ denotes the trace of a matrix, $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$, and $C$ is a normalisation constant.

If $A$ *was* a real matrix, it would follow a [matrix normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution) and could be [sampled easily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution). However, $A$ is a binary matrix in this problem. Is the above a known distribution? Is it possible to draw samples from it efficiently? I would like to avoid sampling the matrix using a Gibbs sampler.

Comment: I doubt you will find a direct simulation method for this Ising-like distribution. E.g., the normalisation constant is most likely intractable.

Comment: The problem I'm facing with a Gibbs sampler is that the probability mass function is quite rough such that the sampler gets stuck in local equilibria. I'll have a look whether I can find an "annealed" Gibbs sampler to do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target probability mass function is of the form
$$\begin{align}p(A)&\propto \exp\left\{-\frac 12 \mathrm{tr}\left[\left(A-M\right)^TV\left(A-M\right)\right]\right\}\\
&\propto \exp\left\{-\frac 12 \sum_{ij}(a_{ji}-\mu_{ji})\sum_{k} v_{jk} (a_{ki}-\mu_{ki})\right\}\\&\propto \exp\left\{-\frac 12 \sum_{ijk}v_{jk}a_{ji}a_{ki}+\frac 12 \sum_{ijk}v_{jk}a_{ji}\mu_{ki}+\frac 12 \sum_{ijk}v_{jk}\mu_{ji}a_{ki}\right\}\\
&\propto\exp\left\{-\frac 12 \sum_{ijk}v_{jk}a_{ji}a_{ki}+\frac 12 \sum_{ij}a_{ji}\left[\sum_k v_{jk}\mu_{ki}+ \sum_k v_{kj}\mu_{ki}\right]\right\}\\&\propto\exp\left\{-\frac 12 \sum_{ijk}v_{jk}a_{ji}a_{ki}+\frac 12 \sum_{ij}a_{ji}\sum_k \left[v_{jk}+ v_{kj}\right]\mu_{ki}\right\}\end{align}$$
if $M=(\mu_{ij})_{ij}$ and $V=(v_{ij})_{ij}$. It is therefore exactly [an Potts model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model#Definition) over $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ and there is no known exact simulation method (apart from [perfect sampling](https://www.ams.jhu.edu/~fill/papers/algo1.pdf)).

Simulation by Gibbs sampling of the Potts model may indeed be quite slow. Accelerating techniques are the [Swendsen–Wang algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swendsen%E2%80%93Wang_algorithm), the [Wolff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolff_algorithm) and [parallel tempering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_tempering).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Do you happen to know whether there are sensible (mean-field) variational approximations, or do they suffer from the same problems as the Gibbs sampler?